# Is there something wrong with my indentation?

Tags: java, indentation, code-formatting

This may be off topic, but a teacher of mine recently said that my indentation was incorrect but gave a very vague reason of what was wrong and I do not think anything is wrong with my indentation when I code. Below is a program I wrote and my teacher said that the indentation is annoying and incorrect to read.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class SecretCode {


    public static boolean isValidLength (String stringChecker) // Checks to see is user the String that was input by the user is valid. 
    {
        if (stringChecker.length() >= 2 && stringChecker.length() <= 12) // Determines how long the String is. 
        {
            return true; // It is valid. 
        }
        else 
        {
            return false; // It is invalid. 
        }
    }

    public static int charToAscii (String stringToAscii) // Converts the String inputted by the user and converts it to an Ascii value. The values are stored and return as an int. 
    {
        int stringValue = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < stringToAscii.length(); x++) // Loop to parse through the String and add all the Ascii values. 
        {
            stringValue += (int) stringToAscii.charAt(x); // Adder. 
        }

        return stringValue; // Returns final value of String. 
    }

    public static int getNumDigits (int totalDigits) // Gets the total number of digits in an int. 
    {
        return (int) (Math.log10(totalDigits) + 1); // This will return the total amount of digits using a logarithmic function You can also do String.valueOf(totalDigits).length(); 
    }

    public static String getSecretCode (int secretCodeConversion) // Converts Ascii values into two separate characters. 
    {
        String secretCode = new String (); // String instantiation. Proper syntax for declaring a String. There is not 

        int num1, num2; // Variable declaration

        num1 = (secretCodeConversion % 10000) / 100; // Splits the numbers into two. This gets first two digits.
        num2 = (secretCodeConversion % 100); // Second two digits.

        if (num1 <= 65)
        {
            num1 += 61; // Ensures a letter is possible.
        }
        if (num2 <= 65)
        {
            num2 += 61; // Ensures a letter is possible for num2. This could have been short-circuited by an 'or' operator. 
        }

        secretCode += Character.toString((char) num1) + Character.toString((char) num2); // Concatenates the two numbers back into a String.

        return secretCode; // Return secret code. 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretCode = new String (); // User input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); // Instantiates Scanner object to read input. 
        System.out.println ("Please enter the String you would like to make a secret code?");
        secretCode = sc.next(); // Input

        while (isValidLength(secretCode) == false) // Checks to see low long secret message it is to make sure it is valid. 
        {
            System.out.println ("Please enter the String you would like to make a secret code?");
            secretCode = sc.next(); // Loops until true. 
        }

        sc.close(); // No more need for Scanner.

        int sumOfDigits = charToAscii(secretCode); // Data for output requirements. 

        if (getNumDigits(sumOfDigits) % 2 != 0)
        {
            sumOfDigits *= 10; 
        }

        if (sumOfDigits <= 4000)
        {
            sumOfDigits *= 4;
        }

        if (getNumDigits(sumOfDigits) % 2 != 0)
        {
            sumOfDigits /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println ("Your Secret Coded Message Is: " + getSecretCode(sumOfDigits));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println ("Additional Data:");
        System.out.println ("_______________________");

        System.out.println ("String Input: " + '"' + secretCode + '"');
        System.out.println ("Sum of Ascii Codes: " + charToAscii(secretCode));
        System.out.println ("Secret Code in Ascii Numbers " + sumOfDigits);
    }
} // This bracket is part of the code, but I could not get the formatting to work.
```

My teacher said that everything was on the left border, but I believe the things that are on the left border do not have any other place to go. I have looked at other programmers and I have looked at other Java code on Github and I think I am doing everything correctly. I do not know what she was talking about?

Comment: All of your methods need to be indented. They shouldn't be at the same indentation level as `public class SecretCode {`

Comment: As long as it's consistent, hard to disagree. Most IDEs will have an automatic formatting tool you can configure and apply by the way.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That is a StackOverFlow Error. In the actual IDE and what was checked, those methods were initially indented.

Comment: @HasnainAli Please make sure code is formatted properly before asking. There were tips in the side bar for how to format code. Besides that problem, I don't see any other indentation errors.

Comment: To get everything indented, copy-paste the code into your question, highlight the code block, then click on the `{}` button (or hit Ctrl+K) to get everything indented four spaces.

Comment: Unless he noticed that you're mixing tabs and spaces, which is hard to tell here.

Comment: @HasnainAli Given that you don't know how to format code on this site, can you verify that your methods are at the same indentation as the class definition, or did that accidentally happen when posting the code here?

Comment: I indented the code so that the "This bracket is part of the code" line is actually part of the code. The only thing that's wrong then is the `class` and imports are over-indented.

Comment: Maybe you could attach the source code, so that we can format it for StackOverflow

Comment: This may help: [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html)

Comment: @steenbergh I know how to add code, but it was not adding it in properly. I tried copy and pasting the entire thing and pasting certain parts of it, but it was still not working. Sorry about that. It did not paste properly. I am working on fixing it.

Comment: your teacher is definitively wrong - as teacher he should teach, that is, explaining WHAT is wrong and how to do it correctly! Just saying it's wrong, is not teaching.

Comment: Why didn't you ask your teacher!? It's his/her job to teach you - why not ask "can you tell me exactly what's wrong with my indentation, and what I should do to fix it?" It's hard for people here to read your teacher's mind! If the teacher can't explain the problem to you, then consider trying to acquire a new teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Not long ago, I reviewed the `Java Coding Conventions` from companies like Oracle, Google, Twitter and Spring. Surprisingly there is quite a bit to say when it comes to `indentation` and `formatting` and here is a brief summary and useful links that could help you write `easy to read` and `maintainable` code.

I wrote a [short article](https://medium.com/@rhamedy/a-short-summary-of-java-coding-best-practices-31283d0167d3) about java coding best practices for those interested to read more.

1. 2-4 spaces for indentation (Google recommends +2 spaces)
2. Line length range recommended should be between `70 to 120 (max)`
3. When it comes to wrapping lines break `after comma` and `before an operator`
4. Keep the opening brace `{` at the end of same line as signature of the method and keywords (i.e. if, for, etc keywords)
5. Use `end of line comments //` only when you have a few words to say about the line. If the length of the comment is more than a few words you should make use of `/* */` or `/* */` for multi line comment
6. When the method signature is long then break to new line and use `8 spaces` to differentiate between method arguments and method body
7. Declare each variable in its own line rather than `int i,j,k;`
8. No space between `method name` and parenthesis `(` however, there should be 1 space between reserved keywords (i.e. if, for) and the parenthesis - this would help easily visually differentiate between method and other constructs
9. Methods are separated by a blank line
10. A blank space should appear after a comma in argument list
11. space pad `operators (i.e. +,-,%, etc.) and`=`
12. Many more - please see the links below

Here is your code using some of the above points

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class SecretCode {

    // Checks to see is user the String that was input by the user is valid.

    public static boolean isValidLength(String stringChecker) {
        // Determines length check
        if ((stringChecker.length() >= 2) && (stringChecker.length() <= 12)) { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Converts the String inputted by the user and converts it to an Ascii value. 
     * The values are stored and return as an int. 
     */
    public static int charToAscii (String stringToAscii) {
        int stringValue = 0;

        // Loop to parse through the String and add all the Ascii values. 

        for (int x = 0; x < stringToAscii.length(); x++) {
            stringValue += (int) stringToAscii.charAt(x); // Adder. 
        }

        return stringValue; 
    }

    /* 
    * Gets the total number of digits in an int.  
    * This will return the total amount of digits using a logarithmic function You 
    * can also do String.valueOf(totalDigits).length();
    */

    public static int getNumDigits (int totalDigits)  {
        return (int) (Math.log10(totalDigits) + 1); 
    }

    // Converts Ascii values into two separate characters.

    public static String getSecretCode (int secretCodeConversion) {
        String secretCode = new String (); 

        // Splits the numbers into two. This gets first two digits
        int num1 = (secretCodeConversion % 10000) / 100; 

        // Second two digits - use proper variable naming i.e. firstTwoDigits, secondDigits etc.
        int num2 = (secretCodeConversion % 100);

        if (num1 <= 65)  {
            num1 += 61; // Ensures a letter is possible.
        }
        if (num2 <= 65) {
            // Ensures a letter is possible for num2. This could have been short-circuited by an 'or' operator.
            num2 += 61;  
        }

        secretCode += Character.toString((char) num1) + Character.toString((char) num2); 

        return secretCode; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretCode = new String (); 

        // Instantiates Scanner object to read input. 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.println ("Please enter the String you would like to make a secret code?");
        secretCode = sc.next();

        // Checks to see low long secret message it is to make sure it is valid. 

        while (isValidLength(secretCode) == false) {
            System.out.println ("Please enter the String you would like to make a secret code?");
            secretCode = sc.next(); // Loops until true. 
        }

        sc.close(); // No more need for Scanner.

        int sumOfDigits = charToAscii(secretCode); 

        if (getNumDigits(sumOfDigits) % 2 != 0) {
            sumOfDigits *= 10; 
        }

        if (sumOfDigits <= 4000) {
            sumOfDigits *= 4;
        }

        if (getNumDigits(sumOfDigits) % 2 != 0) {
            sumOfDigits /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println ("Your Secret Coded Message Is: " + getSecretCode(sumOfDigits));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println ("Additional Data:");
        System.out.println ("_______________________");

        System.out.println ("String Input: " + '"' + secretCode + '"');
        System.out.println ("Sum of Ascii Codes: " + charToAscii(secretCode));
        System.out.println ("Secret Code in Ascii Numbers " + sumOfDigits);
    }
}
```

Here are things you could improve in your code

- Over-commented - sometimes it's clear what a line is doing don't add comment, only add comment when the code is complex and it's hard to read
- Variable naming, make it easy to understand what a variable is storing
- Indentation
- Use of type of comment
- Lack of javadoc comments

There are many positives in your code too. I like the method naming, the way you have divided it into methods. You are on right path, read some of the following coding conventions for java and you are all set.

Oracle Java Style Guide - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Google Java Style Guide - https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Spring Framework Style Guide - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Code-Style

Twitter Java Style Guide - https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md

Comment: Subjective, but indentation is probably better to be 2 spaces. Seems to be the most common defacto standard nowadays (also Google's Java Style). 2 spaces helps you abide to the max 120 line length more easily (most IDEs include indent as part of it). Also 2 spaces helps you see the code without horizontal scrolling in 3-way diffs while merging conflicts.

Comment: IMO something in between 2-4 spaces is way to go. I did notice that Google recommended +2 spaces and some other companies use 4 spaces. I have shared links to a few of the companies coding guidelines that matter (so we are not biased to one)

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are not indented inside the class. They seem to be in the same level as the class on your code. The other method level indentation looks fine. Try to format it in your IDE and you will see the difference. The structure should be similar to below.

```
class Order
{
    // fields

    // constructors

    // methods
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Indentation is a particular standard that we follow across code in all classes uniformly. To start with I can say

1. Your commenting style is not readable in screen width.
2. The start and closing for flower brackets is not same across ex: see main method.

Having said that anybody can have their own style of formatting and indenting there is nothing wrong with it.